# Drawing dotted/dashed circle with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, draw, geometry

Is there any way to draw a dotted or dashed circle in OpenCV, on an image ? Or even a way without using OpenCV on C++ for the same purpose ?

Comment: There is a flag for linetype in most drawing functions, but OpenCV doesn't provide any dotted/dashed line styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open file *opencv/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp*. At line *1317* you find circle implementation:

```
Circle( Mat& img, Point center, int radius, const void* color, int fill )
```

Copy, modify and you're done. Feel free to share any interesting results.